# How to get output headers on dynamic table input in pentaho kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I've got a simple kettle transformation which just does `Table Input -> Text File Output`

The table input however is `SELECT * FROM ${tableName}` 
(with the table coming from a job parameter)

The Text file output just has the filename options and separator set.

The output data rows are written OK, but the header checkbox does nothing and I cannot work out how to generate a header.
I guess it is because I am not explicitly mapping fields in the output stage.

**How can I introduce a header to my output?**

Thx

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that enable "append" disables "header"

See the comment here: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Text+File+Output?focusedCommentId=21104316#comment-21104316

Comment: good to know. Usually when I tick "Append" I also make sure to untick "Header", but I didn't know the header and footer would be disabled. (kind of makes sense, though, but perhaps the UI could gray that option out.

Comment: actually, funny enough: the header is not written, but the footer is (tested with PDI 5.2, same behaviour likely in other versions)